# Making time-index dependent state-space models - where has the Kalman filter gone?

Tags: version-10, time-series

How does one now implement a discrete set of state space models?

I had used `KalmanFilter` in the old TimeSeries application, but was keen on trying to do all this in the "new paradigm" of StateSpaceModel[] in *Mathematica* 10.

*Mathematica*'s own docs for the TimeSeries package has a [section](http://reference.wolfram.com/applications/timeseries/UsersGuideToTimeSeries/StructuralModelsAndTheKalmanFilter/1.9.2.html) on state-space form and the Kalman Filter.

Fundamentally I want to make F and G time-index dependent lists of matrices.

Ultimately I want to implement a time-varying CAPM model as described in Tsay using *Mathematica* 10.

Ideas?

Comment: What exactly is the question? You are looking for `KalmanEstimator` I think. And `StateSpaceModel` is not new btw, it's been there since V8.

Comment: The question was in the first line. The now deprecated TimeSeries package had a function called KalmanFilter that supported not just a single StateSpaceModel (i.e. {a,b,c,d} as in the documentation) but a list of them.

Comment: I found this in the documentation: "However, if any one of F, G, Q, R, c, d is time dependent, the above arguments to KalmanFilter, F, G, Q, R, c, d, should be replaced by {Fm+2, Fm+3, ..., FT+1}, {Gm+1, Gm+2, ..., GT}, {Qm+2, Qm+3, ..., QT+1}, {Rm+1, Rm+2, ..., RT}, {cm+2, cm+3, ..., cT+1}, and {dm+1, dm+2, ..., dT}, respectively."

Comment: I see... It seems you're right and Mathematica doesn't support time-dependent Kalman filtering out of the box right now. On the other hand (and I'm guessing you know that), it is fairly easy to implement this functionality yourself (at least for simple models).